# Android ListFragment in Tabs not showing on back button return

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a (relatively) simple drill down application.

It has one Activity (MainActivity) that contains and transitions Fragments.

```
public void goToPartnumbers(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    ft.replace(R.id.container, new IdentifierFragment()).addToBackStack("partnumber").commit();
}
```

`IdentifierFragment` is a tab layout a la http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

```
public class IdentifierFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private FragmentStatePagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private MainActivity mContext;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Part Numbers", "OEM Numbers" };

public IdentifierFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.partnumber_list, container, false);
    // Initialization
    mContext = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = mContext.getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    resetAdapter( new IdentifierFragmentAdapter(mContext.getSupportFragmentManager()) );

    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
    ...I can show you the rest but I don't think it's relevant

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDetach(){
    super.onDetach();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    resetAdapter(null);
}

public void resetAdapter(FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter){
    actionBar.removeAllTabs();
    viewPager.removeAllViews();
    mAdapter = adapter;
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

...
}
```

The two child fragments are both ListFragments with CursorLoaders. When a row is selected, the `IdentifierFragment` is replaced using the following method:

```
public void goToGallery(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    galleryHandle = new GalleryFragment();
    HashMap<String,String> selection = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (HashMap<? extends String, ? extends String> c : mCriteria){
        selection.putAll(c);
    }
    galleryHandle.setSelection(selection);
    ft.replace(R.id.container, galleryHandle).addToBackStack("gallery").commit();
}
```

When I move into the `IdentifierFragment`, it works fine. I can then select a row and go into the detail view. It's when I attempt to use the back button from the detail view that I get the `ViewPager`, but no `ListViews`!

Obviously I can supply whatever other code is needed. I just supplied what I thought was immediately relevant.

I'm at a loss, and would very much like any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because you replace the current fragment.
Perhaps if you use .add() instead of .replace() when you go to a new gallery

```
public void goToGallery(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    galleryHandle = new GalleryFragment();
    HashMap<String,String> selection = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (HashMap<? extends String, ? extends String> c : mCriteria){
        selection.putAll(c);
    }
    galleryHandle.setSelection(selection);
    ft.add(R.id.container, galleryHandle).addToBackStack("gallery").commit();
}
```

Comment: It's not that. If I do that, then the tabs are removed (like I had gone into the Gallery) but the listview is still front and center (it doesn't respond to actions though).